# CPU fan constantly going up and down

Tags: cpu, fan, temperature

Edit: No solution have been found. A long time latter I changed from Kubuntu to Ubuntu + Cinnamon and I don't have that problem anymore.

When my computer is at rest (e.g. no application open, just after boot), the CPU fan is always speeding, stopping, then speeding again... on a ~20 seconds basis, which is quiet annoying.

I check my cpu temperature, and it is indeed going up and down, hence the fan speeding to cool it. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tYE0.png) is the evolution of my cpu temp.

I am running Kubuntu 18.04, with a Ryzen 7 2700X and a motherboard with X470  chipset. The CPU fan is the stock fan provided by AMD. The computer is not a laptop.

This could be poor temperature management or a process that periodically uses CPU, but I have no idea how to check either option.

Edit: [Here](https://pastebin.com/J3FGcwTZ) is a `$ top` output with absolutely nothing running, and [here](https://pastebin.com/QZ7c5GMc) with a low activity (meaning: I have ksysguard and firefox open, and I'm moving/resizing windows). Xorg is working (which is normal) but is 6% too much?

Edit 2: I changed the thermal paste of the processor. There is a slight improvement of the minimal temperature I read (30°C instead of 33°C) but the problem remains.

Comment: Tu peux voir dans "Table des processus" si un processus utilise beaucoup en cpu ? / Can you see in "Process Table" if a process use a lot of cpu ?

Comment: @JerareYoshi I am not sure there is one. I edited the question to add $top output